# Apache sirviendo Django y Wordpress simultanemente

Tags: django, wordpress, apache

Tengo una web creada en Wordpress que esta en `/var/www/sitio1` que esta todo bien, dicho sitio esta por el puerto 80 y su dirección es `ejemplo.com`.

Ahora, tengo otro sitio creado en Django que está en el puerto 8000, ubicado en la carpeta `/var/www/sitio2`.

Ahora, quiero poner ese sitio web de Django como una subcarpeta del primero, es decir, cuando pidan esta dirección: `http://ejemplo.com/servicios` me abra el sitio hecho con Django y claro, que lo hagan por el mismo puerto 80.

Especifico el puerto 80 por que ya he logrado hacerlo por el puerto 8000, pero queda así `http://ejemplo.com:8000/servicios` y realmente no me gustaría de esa manera. No soy experto en Apache, por lo que realmente no sé si se pueda hacer.

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer usando [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) de apache

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost on

<Proxy *>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from All
</Proxy>

<Location /servicios>
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000/
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8000/
</Location>
```

Con esto todas las peticiones que lleguen a /servicios van a ser internamente redireccionadas al puerto 8000.